# How to acces this div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I need to access the class `chat-wrapper`[image: Root]

I've tried all of those options

```
// 1 --> error: document.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.getElementByClassName is not a function at HTMLElement
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.getElementsByClassName('chat-wrapper')

// 2 --> null
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.querySelector('chat-wrapper')

// 3 error: document.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.getElementByTagName is not a function at HTMLElement
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName('div')

// 4 --> undefined
document.querySelector('df-messenger').shadowRoot.querySelector('df-messenger-chat').shadowRoot.div
```

But none of them seem to work. How could I access that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".chat-wrapper");
```

or

```
document.querySelector("div.chat-wrapper");
```

Remember: querySelector() returns the **first** Element within the document that matches the specified selector

Use dot(.) character to call an element with its class, or sharp(#) character to call an element with its id.

Read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)